# Passing Spring Boot Property Bean to Classes in other Projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I am configuring a spring boot application. So I created a property bean class like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class APPStaticProperties {

    @NotNull
    @Value("${dblog.system.name}")
    String db_logsystem_name;

    /**
     * @return the db_logsystem_name
     */
    public String getDb_logsystem_name() {
        return db_logsystem_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param db_logsystem_name the db_logsystem_name to set
     */
    public void setDb_logsystem_name(String db_logsystem_name) {
        this.db_logsystem_name = db_logsystem_name;
    }

}
```

And I am creating a object by in the controller class:

```
@Autowired
APPStaticProperties appStaticProperties;
```

But I wanted to know how do I pass the this object for use in other projects? Because my code flow goes from the controller to a JSP and then to a class in another project. I need the object available for use in that class. Well to be honest, in many other projects as well! I am not able to figure it out how to do it. Neither are there too many examples out there for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally inject an @Configuration bean into other Spring managed beans, because it sets up configuration to be used by other Spring managed beans.

For example, because you have declared an @PropertySource, to access your properties in other Spring managed means you can just inject properties into your code elsewhere using @Value. You don't need to inject your APPStaticProperties bean to do this.